# Error: Could not convert from sensor[] to sensor

Tags: c++, syntax, arduino

I already have this class

```
class sensor : iElectronicParts{
    // Some stuff here like methods and properties
};
```

For accessing all sensors I want to store them in a new object with type of `global`, so I just coded this class (there's no `set` method because I already ran into an error)

```
class global {
  public:
  sensor getSensors() {
    return sensors; // This line throws the error
  }

  private:
  sensor sensors[10];
};
```

and I got this error message

> Compiling sketch...
>
> /tmp/538691267/200119_Growbox/200119_Growbox.ino: In member function
>   'sensor global::getSensors()':
>
> /tmp/538691267/200119_Growbox/200119_Growbox.ino:335:12: error: could
>   not convert '((global*)this)->global::sensors' from 'sensor [10]' to
>   'sensor'
>
> return sensors;
>
> ^~~~~~~
>
> exit status 1

I did not instantiated this object yet, I only defined the class. If I replace every type definition of `sensor` by `int` it works.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong / what I have to do to fix this?

Comment: A `sensor` isn't the same thing as an array of `sensor`.

Comment: While the now deleted answer gave the wrong solution, the problem was described correctly: An array is not the same as a single element of the array. While Arduino have their own library and "standard" classes, I still recommend that you invest and spend some time reading [a few good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing an array of `sensor` in your class, but `GetSensors` is trying to return a copy of a single `sensor`. There's no conversion from an array to a single `sensor`, so your compiler doesn't know what it needs to do.

The question here is what you *want* to do: Do you want the whole list, or do you want to get a single sensor.

### If You want to return the whole array.

C++ does not support arrays as return types. You will have to return a *pointer* to the first element in your array.

The code would look like this:

```
  sensor* getSensors() {
    return sensors;
  }
```

and you would use it like this, assuming `g` is an instance of global:

```
sensor* sensors = g.getSensors();
Serial.print(sensors[3].value);
```

This code uses what is called **array to pointer decay**. Callers of your getSensors function will no longer know what the size of the array is, you have to make sure to not go over bounds! As this returns a pointer to the original sensors, any modifications that you do later to the returned pointer will affect the array in the instance of global.

### If you want to return a specific sensor

You just need to change your getSensors function to take as an argument the index of the sensor that you care about. It would look like this:

```
sensor& getSensor(int index) {
    return sensors[index];
  }
```

This returns a *reference* to a specific sensor. As with the pointer case, changes to the returned sensor will affect the original array inside the instance of `global` (which I assume is the intent)

If you do not want to make modifications to the original array, you should return by value, and omit the `&` from the return type.

Answer (score 1):

**getSensors()** function's return type is a mismatch. you should return a **sensor object** then have to choose one of the **sensors[index]** or change the return type to **sensor pointer**. <s>however, I advice to use **stl** types (you do not have to but it is the best way)</s> @divinas has inform me that no std::array in ardunio so this advice is not applicable:

```
#include <memory>
#include <array>
class iElectronicParts{};

class sensor : iElectronicParts{
    // Some stuff here like methods and properties
};

class global {
  public:
    std::array<sensor, 10>& getSensors() {
    return sensors; 
  }

  private:
  std::array<sensor, 10> sensors;
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, however there's no std::array in the standard arduino library